# thickness of \lfloor and \vert

Tags: arrays, delimiters, vertical

For some reason, I have to use both `\lfloor` and `\left\vert`
in my latex file. But as the number of lines increase, it is clear that their thickness are not the same, which does not look nice to me :(

Here is the minimal working environment together with a screenshot of the output.

The `\lfloor` is clearly thicker than `\vert`.

**My question**: Is there a way to set the same thickness for both of them?

Any help is highly appreciated.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
&\begin{array}{l}
\text{for}\;n=0,1,\ldots\\
\left\vert\left\lfloor
\begin{array}{l}
\text{for some reason, I have a mixture of
\texttt{lfloor} and \texttt{vert}}\\
\text{but their thickness are not the same}\\
\text{what are my options?}\\
\text{I would like the same thickness for both of them}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mathabx` does have a `\thickvert` extensible delimiter symbol. You probably do not want to use `mathabx` otherwise, so you need to follow [those steps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388) to only load this symbol. Then you can use `\thickvert` to get

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\thickvert}{0}{mathb}{"7E}{mathx}{"1F}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text{for}\;n=0,1,\ldots\\
\left\thickvert\left\lfloor
\begin{array}{l}
\text{for some reason, I have a mixture of
\texttt{lfloor} and \texttt{vert}}\\
\text{but their thickness are not the same}\\
\text{what are my options?}\\
\text{I would like the same thickness for both of them}
\end{array}
\right.\right.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works like a charm for me :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the vertical rules using `\vrule` and add a little horizontal rule with `\rule`. Make sure to align the inner `tabular` at the `[b]`ottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ l }
    \text{for } n = 0, 1, \dots \\
    \hspace{.5em}% Space between left margin of tabular cell and first \vrule
    \vrule \hspace{.5em}% Vertical rule + space to next \vrule
    \vrule \rule[-.4em]{.5ex}{.4pt}% Vertical rule with little horizontal line
    \begin{tabular}[b]{ l }
      for some reason, I have a mixture of \texttt{lfloor} and \texttt{vert} \\
      but their thickness are not the same                                   \\
      what are my options?                                                   \\
      I would like the same thickness for both of them
    \end{tabular}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```